# Find all entries with exclusions in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, find

I have a model called "image" and I need to find all images with the exception of those images that contain the expression "User" in the name attribute of the image.

Image.rb:

```
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
end
```

So, it should be something like:

@images = Image.where("name !=~ '/user/i'")

What is the correct term?

Comment: Generally you don't use regular expressions in SQL, and certainly in your situation there's no need to. A simple `NOT LIKE` clause will be sufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PostgreSQL in Rails 4:

```
Image.where.not("name ~ ?", "User")
```

MySQL in Rails 4:

```
Image.where.not("name RLIKE ?", "User")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@images = Image.where.not(name: user)
```

Or if "user" is string:

```
@images = Image.where.not(name: "user")
```

Comment: Ok, but it should be a REGEXP, so the :name should not contain the word "user". E.g. "First user" should bot be a result...

Answer (score 0):

Try This

@images = Image.where.not("name='user'")

Comment: I added a commoon below too: it should be a REGEXP, so the :name should not contain the word "user". E.g. "First user" should not be a result... your expression excludes all images where the :name == 'user' I guess.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the `squeel` gem (https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/squeel) then you can do:

```
exclusion_value = "user"
Image.where{name !~ exclusion_value}
```